# Using sox to generate a square wave signal

Tags: linux, audio, sox

I have a script (http://paste.ubuntu.com/24497460/) which uses sox to generate a wave form from a series of "pulses" and "spaces" generated by lirc from a remote control. The script creates a 19kHz sine wave for the pulses and "silence" for the spaces.

I would like to convert the resulting wave file to digital data (where the pulses (and their length) mark a one and the spaces a zero. Since this is on-off-keying there are various tools to do this for me. The problem is that those tools require the ones to be "maximum volume", instead of a sine wave.

My question is - what can I use with sox to generate periods of "high volume"? Like the "pad" option, but outputting maximum volume instead of 0?

Comment: Use `square` instead of `sine`? See `man sox`. This should be max volume, use `gain` effect to change volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. I used square instead of sine, as @dirkt suggested, but I had to lower the square wave frequency enough so that a "square" period is greater than my longest bit length. I tried a 10Hz square wave and here is the diff:

```
<       SOX_OPT="${SOX_OPT} synth ${LEN}s square 10 0 0" # square wave 10Hz
---
>       SOX_OPT="${SOX_OPT} synth ${LEN}s sine 19k 0 0 sine 19k 0 50" # sine wave 19kHz 2ch phase shift
```

The results look like this:

- modulated sine wave:

  [image: Modulated sine wave]
- square signal:

  [image: square signal]